# Quiero saber si una propiedad de un objeto está vacía o no, ¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?, ya traté con null, =[] y no funciona

Tags: javascript

Tengo este objeto y quiero saber si la propiedad "subjects" está vacía

```
{
  "_id": "641c8ec0705c95502845910f",
  "first_name": "Rebecca",
  "last_name": "Kuphal",
  "subjects": [],
  "__v": 0
}
const teacher = await TeacherModel.findById(id);

return res.send(teacher.subjects);
```

Comment: Que variable necesitas saber si está vacía? Por favor, comparte qué has probado y explícalo un poco más

Comment: Si una propiedad no está definida, al intentar leerla obtienes `undefined`. Si es un arreglo o una cadena puedes leer la propiedad `length` y será 0 si está vacío.

Answer (score 1):

En javascript tienes varios "conceptos"

- `undefined` : Se refiere a una variable que no existe o no ha sido asignada.
- `null` : Es un posible valor de una variable, es asignada por el programador
- `0` El número cero. (En un array vacio array.length retorna cero)
- `""` String vacío

Todos estos elementos (y otros) se agrupan en un concepto llamado [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), que se refiere a elementos que a la hora de evaluarlos como si fueran *Booleanos* retornan `false`

Ejemplo

```js
if(!undefined){
  console.log("undefined es falso");
}
if(!null){
  console.log("null es falso");
}
if(!0){
  console.log("0 es falso");
}
if(!""){
  console.log('"" es falso');
}
```

Esto siempre y cuando **NO** comparemos con igualdad estricta `===`

```js
console.log(undefined==null==0=="");
console.log(undefined===null===0==="");
```

En resumen basta que hagas un `if` a tu variable

Èjemplo

```js
let objeto = {}; //objeto sin propiedades
if(!objeto.propiedad1){
   console.log("propiedad1 undefined")
}
//---------------------------------------------


objeto.propiedad1 = null // asignamos nulo
if(!objeto.propiedad1){
   console.log("propiedad1 nula")
}
//---------------------------------------------


objeto.propiedad1 = 0 // asignamos cero. 
if(!objeto.propiedad1){
   console.log("propiedad1 cero")
}
//---------------------------------------------

objeto.propiedad1 = []; //asignamos un array
if(!objeto.propiedad1){
   console.log("propiedad1 falsa")
}
else{
  console.log("propiedad1 verdadera")
}

//un array vacio retorna verdadero al evaluarlo como booleando, no así si comparamos con su largo ya que retorna cero


if(!objeto.propiedad1.length){
   console.log("propiedad1 falsa")
}
else{
  console.log("propiedad1 verdadera")
}


//---------------------------------------------
objeto.propiedad1 = "valor valido"; //asignamos un valor que retorna verdadero al evaluar como booleano
if(!objeto.propiedad1){
   console.log("propiedad1 con problema")
}
else{
  console.log("propiedad1 con un valor correcto")
}
```

Comment: La respuesta está bien, pero no puedo decir lo mismo de la pregunta. Necesita aclaraciones.

Comment: Bastaba con citar al OP unas lecturas fundamentales de JS.

Comment: @Mateo Entonces el comentario debería ir en la pregunta y no en la respuesta, pero gracias por tu aprobación, espero se vea reflejada en la votación